# Dynamic fields repeat the same data in text-field v-model

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

How could I improve this code, I'm creating dynamic fields that are created depending on the user input, but I have a problem when inserting the information in one field it replicates in the other fields, I want every new field fills independently and send that data to points.compartments_detail

I know the problem is in v-model="points.compartments_detail", because when I delete it lets me write every field independently.

points.compartments_detail is set as an empty array

```
 </v-row>
  <v-text-field
    v-model="points.number_compartments"
    label="COMPARTIMIENTOS"
    outlined
    :disabled="actionQuotation === 'VER'"
    type="number"
    @change="logSelect(), addCompartmentCapacity(points.number_compartments),deleteComparmentCapacity(points.number_compartments) "
    class="mx-3"
    dense
  />
</v-row>
<v-row v-for="(compartment, index) in comparment_capacity" :key="index" class="mx-0">
 <v-row v-if="points.number_compartments > 1">
  <v-text-field
    v-model="points.compartments_detail"
    label="ESPECIFICAR CAPACIDAD DE COMPARTIMIENTO" 
    outlined
    :disabled="actionQuotation === 'VER'"
     class="mx-3"
     dense
     hint="Ejemplo: 1000 galones / Click en boton agregar para añadir mas campos"
    />
   </v-row>
 </v-row>
```

This is my data :

```
comparment_capacity : [{comparment : ""}],
```

The functions to create and delete the fields

```
addCompartmentCapacity (item) {
  while(this.comparment_capacity.length < item){
      this.comparment_capacity.push({
        compartment : ""
    })
  }
},
deleteComparmentCapacity (item){
  while(this.comparment_capacity.length > item ) {
    if(this.comparment_capacity.length > 1){
      this.comparment_capacity.pop()
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Any ideas will be of great help.

Answer (score 1):

for test this sample here >>> [Sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/addparagraph-9h6xqu?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue:385-751).
Is this what you looking for?
**Paragraph** is for default value you can delete it if not needed.
**Entered.num** is the important for push more input.

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <div v-for="(x,index) in Paragraph" :key="x">
      <input
        placeholder="Type here"
        v-model="x.Text1"
        @keyup="GetText($event,index)"
      />
    </div>

    <input
      placeholder="Add Paragraph"
      v-model="Entered.num"
      @keyup="Get(Entered.num)"
    />
  </div>
</template>
```

```
data() {
    return {
      Entered: [{ num: 0 }],
      Paragraph: [
        {
          Text1: "Hello World1",
        },
        {
          Text1: "Hello World2",
        },
      ],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    Get(num) {
      while (num--) {
        this.Paragraph.push({ Text1: "" });
      }
    },
    GetText(event) {
       console.log(event.target.value , 'Index: ',index);
    },
  },
```

Comment: what I need is that when a new input is created, all the information of each one of them is saved in the v-model points.compartments_detail

Comment: when a new input is created you can control them inside the **this.paragraph.push** add the information you want on **Text1**, when user typing inside the input get can capture the value using v-model and which paragraph user typed get from the index value. Default value get from the paragraph you can modified easily inside the data()

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/addparagraph-9h6xqu?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue:807-858 check this example